# Access Runtime on Wine, buttons not working

Tags: ms-access, ubuntu-12.04, wine

Has anyone run into the problem where Access runtime is working, as it opens the project file and opens the oleDB connection to database, but none of the buttons that are on Access project are working? By this, I mean I can press those buttons but nothing happens.

What should I do to make those buttons work with Wine too?